# How can I get data from server to the android when the user is in a WebView

Tags: android, webview

I know that about sending and getting data in android well.But **I always do this operations when I am in the activity that it have no a `WebView` and it does not use the `WebView`**. Now my question is if my activity is as a `WebView` and I 
submitted some data to the android, How can I get the data in the `WebView`? For example consider the user sees a page from a website by `WebView`, Now he submit data to the server using the `WebView` environment and then  the server responses to the request. So, how can I get the data from the server when  the user is in a `WebView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of approach is made in payment gateway integration in android. You have to override a javascript method in you web view activity and make server call that method with the desired response.

To get the idea see citrus Android integration
http://www.citruspay.com/DevelopersGuide/#/

See Android Integration and return url part.

```
private class JsInterface {

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void pgResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

}

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(), "CitrusResponse");
```

In server side do like this (PHP)

```
echo postResponse('$json_object'); // data to de posted here
```

In this way your js interface in android app will get the response yo needed

Answer (score 0):

Let the WebView load a website of yours, where user interaction is managed by JavaScript. If there is some data to pass to the Android-layer, call the Java-methods via JavascriptInterface.

A JavascriptInterface is a simple Java class, that annotates its methods with `@JavascriptInterface`. Those methods could be called from the JavaScript on the page of your webview.

Read up here for more detail https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html